# Checkbox value added by default

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, default

I'm attempting to make a code that will display the divs when checked and also add the values of the checkboxes together. I've managed to come up with this but now I want to make some of the checkboxes checked and their values added together by default. I can make the checkbox checked, however, I need the value to be added by default as well. Any help would be appreciated. Here is my code:
a
    This is the first paragraph 
    This is the second paragraph 
    This is the third paragraph

```
<form name="formex">

<input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" class="classone" type="checkbox" name="one" value="10"> $10.00<br>
<input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" type="checkbox"  name="two" value="12"> $12.00<br>
<input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" type="checkbox" name="three" value="1"> $1.00<br>
<input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" type="checkbox" name="four" value="2"> $2.00<br>
<input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" type="checkbox" name="five" value="24"> $24.00<br>

<br>
<input id="total" type="text" name="total">
</form>
```

My script

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
var total = document.getElementById("total")
function clickCh(caller){
if(caller.checked){
add(caller)
} else {
subtract(caller)
}}

function add(caller){   total.value = total.value*1 + caller.value*1}
function subtract(caller){  total.value = total.value*1 - caller.value*1}


function showPara()
       {
            document.getElementById("first").style.display=(document.formex.one.checked) ? "inline" : "none";
            document.getElementById("second").style.display=(document.formex.two.checked) ? "inline" : "none";
           document.getElementById("third").style.display=(document.formex.three.checked) ? "inline" : "none";
            return true;
        }
</script>
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TCZ6t/1/

Comment: I know this is unrelated to your question, but consider changing the IDs to something like `item1, item2, ... itemn` so in your JS you can use a for loop `getElementById("item"+i)`

Comment: Definitely. I will do this. Thank you.

Comment: If you change the IDs as David says then you can write a function to loop through and total all check boxes. then you do not need the add() and subtract() functions and you can simply run the function once at the beginning of the script to take into account any defaults.

Comment: I'm very new to javascript and I wouldn't even know how to begin this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just add the attribute "checked" to the end of the tag to have it checked by default. In other words, if I wanted $10 to be checked by default I would just change the tag to:

```
<input checked onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" class="classone" type="checkbox" name="one" value="10" checked> $10.00<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just loop all the checked checkboxes and call the `add` method like

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="formex"] input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    if (els[i].checked) {
        add(els[i])
    }
}
```

Demo:

```js
var total = document.getElementById("total");

function clickCh(caller) {
  if (caller.checked) {
    add(caller)
  } else {
    subtract(caller)
  }
}

function add(caller) {
  total.value = total.value * 1 + caller.value * 1
}

function subtract(caller) {
  total.value = total.value * 1 - caller.value * 1
}


function showPara() {
  document.getElementById("first").style.display = (document.formex.one.checked) ? "inline" : "none";
  document.getElementById("second").style.display = (document.formex.two.checked) ? "inline" : "none";
  document.getElementById("third").style.display = (document.formex.three.checked) ? "inline" : "none";
  return true;
}

var els = document.querySelectorAll('form[name="formex"] input[type="checkbox"]');
for (var i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
  if (els[i].checked) {
    add(els[i])
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="first" style="display:none;">This is the first paragraph</div> <br />
<div id="second" >This is the second paragraph</div> <br />
<div id="third" style="display:none;">This is the third paragraph</div>  <br />

<form name="formex">
    <input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" class="classone" type="checkbox" name="one" value="10"/> $10.00<br/>
    <input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" type="checkbox"  name="two" value="12"/> $12.00<br/>
    <input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" type="checkbox" name="three" value="1"/> $1.00<br/>
    <input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" type="checkbox" name="four" value="2" checked /> $2.00<br/>
    <input onclick="clickCh(this) ; showPara()" type="checkbox" name="five" value="24" checked /> $24.00<br/>
    
    <br/>
    <input id="total" type="text" name="total"/>
</form>
```